# Counter for Towers Of Hanoi

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

I have written a code for Towers Of Hanoi game. I don't know how to implement a counter for this program on how many times it ran. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nDisks = 3;
    doTowers(nDisks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
  }

  public static void doTowers(int topN, char from, char inter, char to) {
    if (topN == 1){
      System.out.println("Disk 1 from " + from + " to " + to);
    }else {
      doTowers(topN - 1, from, to, inter);
      System.out.println("Disk " + topN + " from " + from + " to " + to);
      doTowers(topN - 1, inter, from, to);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just joined this site. Sorry.

Comment: @John Smith Have fun. :)

Answer (score 10):

Change the return type of `doTowers` from `void` to `int`, and set the return value to:

1. if `topN == 1`, return 1;
2. else return the sum of two `doTowers()` plus 1.

The logic is similar to the algorithm of the problem. Have fun figuring it out!

You could also use a static global variable, but that's arguably bad programming style.

Comment: Sorry could you post the code. I didn't understand what you mean. Thank You

Comment: @JohnSmith: That's the spirit and the fun! Congrats:)

Comment: @JohnSmith if you got it to work you should award Ziyao the answer credit.